# How to add several jrxml files into one master jrxml?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I would like to know whether it is possible to assemble a single report with the given structure using DynamicJasper.

The structure:

```
existing jrxml header
jrxml generated by Java class using dynamicjasper, holding dynamic data fetched from database
existing jrxml footer
```

thank you for your attention

Comment: Are you having issues assembling the report? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried dynamicjasper -> addConcatenatedReport, but failed, possibly due to lack of information

Comment: Can you show your code and exactly where you're having issues?

Comment: Are you talking about subreports in one report or a jrxml template?